# I have successfully assigned the capability for a custom role but plugin menu still not visible for my custom role

Tags: php, wordpress

Here my code--

```php
function add_custom_cap() {
  $roles = get_editable_roles();
  $role = get_role('admin');
  //admin is a custom role
  $capabilities = array('cap1', 'cap2', 'cap3');
  foreach($capabilities as $cap) {
    $role->add_cap($cap);
  }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_custom_cap');
```

whats wrong any solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

```
function add_custom_cap() {
$roles = get_editable_roles();
$role = get_role( 'admin' );
$capabilities = array('cap1', 'cap2', 'cap3');
foreach( $capabilities as $cap ) {
    $role->add_cap( $cap ); <---- you are passing array...
}
}
     add_action('admin_init','add_custom_cap' );
```

add_cap() < --- is this a type of string ? or an array ?....
try to use print_f or var_dump...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer, only another question. Please use the comments instead.